# How can I get a calendar event object when create/save on Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to create a Google Calendar add-on and I want to connect it to an external API to send the created event object to my API but I can't find a way to do that.
I found the [CalendarTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/calendar-trigger-builder) class but only triggers the event on the update, not on create.

Is there a trigger for creating an event? or a way to get that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you mentioned, the `onEventUpdated` function "Specifies a trigger that fires when a calendar entry is created, updated, or deleted." Does that help to answer your question?

Comment: I spend some time testing and I did notice that my trigger was being disabled for some "unknown" reason. But now it's working

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.